# Unexpected token '=' on react js

Tags: reactjs

i've created reactjs app when starting reactjs project, getting unexpected token error at line 4 on index file. the index file is given below.

```
> 4 |     static propTypes = {
    |                      ^
  5 |         value: PropTypes.string,
  6 |         onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  7 |     }
```

following is index.js file

```
static propTypes = {
        value: PropTypes.string,
        onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isGoing: true,
            numberOfGuests: 2,
            calendarOpened: false,
            selected: [],
            day: new Date().getDate(),
            month: new Date().getMonth() + 1,
            year: new Date().getFullYear()
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('number of guest: ' + this.state.numberOfGuests);
        alert('is going: ' + this.state.isGoing);
    }
    selectDate (evt) {
        this.setState({ selected: evt.iso, calendarOpened: false })
    }
    // this is to display different months or years
    // without it we would only have one calendar page
    changeInfo ({ day, month, year }) {
        this.setState({ day, month, year })
    }

    openCalendar () {
        this.setState({calendarOpened: true})
    }
```

Comment: Show us **full** class. I think you have syntax error above the `static propTypes`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs since Standard ES6 classes can only have methods, not properties.
You have to install `babel-preset-stage-0` which adds support for class properties.

```
npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev
```

Then configure `.babelrc` to use this preset:

```
//...
presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0']
//...
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to change current babel/webpack settings you can always move `propTypes` definition outside of the component:

```
ComponentName = (props) => <div>my component</div>
ComponentName.propTypes {
  ...your prop types...
}
```

Comment: i have install npm install babel-preset-stage-0 --save-dev but it's not work..Missing class properties transform on static keyword.

Comment: Can you please share your source code? Otherwise, you can always move the `propTypes` definition outside of the component. I will update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. You no need to install prop-types seperately. You can call PropTypes using React like below

```
static get propTypes(){
   return {
        value: React.PropTypes.string
    }
}
```

Or else

You can install prop-types module and define prop data types

Install prop-types

```
npm install —save prop-types

import PropTypes from ‘prop-types’;

static get propTypes(){
   return {
     value: PropTypes.string
   }
```

Since you already installed React so go with first option. You no need to install prop-types again

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Your code looks like you are declaring a static variable and react doesn’t understand that. It’s a get function so you have to define it as a function as I mentioned in my answer

Comment: i will change above code but PropTypes is not defined error is there

Comment: Install prop-types I.e., npm install - -save prop-types and import it in your component like import PropTypes from ‘prop-types’;

Comment: i install above prop-type but it can't work ..Unexpected token error is come all time..

Comment: Updated my post please check

Comment: Failed prop type: The prop `onChange` is marked as required in `DatePicker`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in DatePicker

Comment: It looks like your prop type issue is resolved. You are not passing mandatory Param onChange to Datepicker so you need to pass that to Datepicker component. Your code should be fine